# $x^3-6x^2+2x-2=0$ solve for x

Tags: polynomials, cubics

I solved it by approximation but its very long way to solve, so i was wondering if there is a quicker way to solve this kind of questions.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation

Comment: There is no easy method to solve for $x$ exactly.

Comment: The real solution is $$2+\sqrt[3]{\frac{63+\sqrt{969}}{9}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{63-\sqrt{969}}{9}}$$ Nothing particularly neat nor interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use [General cubic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula)

Or for another way:

$$x^3-6x^2+2x-2=0$$
$$\implies (x-2)^3 - 10(x-2) -14 = 0$$

Let $t = x - 2$, then:

$$t^3 - 10t -14 = 0$$

And then apply [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula)

Either way, the result will just be:

$$x = 2+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{63+\sqrt{969}}{9}}+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{63-\sqrt{969}}{9}}$$

Comment: Thanks, but what i didn't know how you get to (x-2)^3 - 10(x-2) - 14 = 0

Comment: @DarkNight $x^3 - 6x^2 + 2x - 2 = 0 \implies x^3 - 6x^2 + 12x - 8 − 10x + 20 − 14 = 0 \implies (x-2)^3 - 10(x-2) -14 = 0$

Comment: @DarkNight That's a *linear Tschirnhaus-transformation*: Substituting $y=x+a_{n-1}/n$ in a polynomial of degree $n$ produces a polynomial where the coefficient of $y^{n-1}$ vanishes.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @The 2nd's excellent answer, you can ask a computer to find the solution for you. It is very fast. Here is an exemple in the Python language with the sympy module. It gives you a list of the three complex solutions

```
>>> from sympy.solvers import solve
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> solve(x**3-6*x**2+2*x-2, x)
[2 + (-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(sqrt(969)/9 + 7)**(1/3) + 10/(3*(-1/2 - 
sqrt(3)*I/2)*(sqrt(969)/9 + 7)**(1/3)), 2 + 10/(3*(-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)* 
(sqrt(969)/9 + 7)**(1/3)) + (-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(sqrt(969)/9 + 7)**(1/3), 
10/(3*(sqrt(969)/9 + 7)**(1/3)) + 2 + (sqrt(969)/9 + 7)**(1/3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you prefer the nice
$$x=2 \left(1+\sqrt{\frac{10}{3}} \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{21
   }{10}\sqrt{\frac{3}{10}}\right)\right)\right)$$ that you could easily obtain using the steps given in the Wikipeadia page.